# Permissibility Of Unneeded Hysterectomy

Tags: halacha, women, medicine

Is it halachically ok for a woman have a [hysterectomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysterectomy) if there is no medical need? If not, is it permissible as a form of contraceptive?

Comment: see Nishmat Avraham vol. 3, pp. 56ff for sources at length

Answer (score 4):

That's a dispute between Tane Kamah and R' Yehuda regarding the [prohibition of castrating](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A1#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%94) in [Tosefta Makos 4 4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tosefta_Makkot.4.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

> המסרס את האדם ואת הבהמה ואת החיה ואת העוף,
>   בין גדולים בין קטנים,
>   **בין זכרים ובין נקבות**
>   – הרי זה חייב (מלקות).
>   רבי יהודה אומר: מסרס את הזכרים – חייב,
>   ואת הנקבות – פטור (מהתורה, אבל אסור מדרבנן).

(Tane Kame says removing woman's reproductory system transgresses the Negative commandment Deorayso, and R' Yehudah says, that it is not (Deorayso as women are not commanded on reproduction, but still forbidden Derabanan)

Most of the following Poskim Follow R"Y's approach, making it forbidden Derabanan.